# get the index of the array in php

Tags: php, foreach, key

I have an array that contains the following:

```
$code_ids
 [138]=>
  string(0) "asdsad"
  [126]=>
  string(0) ""
  [163]=>
  string(0) "asdasd"
  [162]=>
  string(0) ""
  [135]=>
  string(0) "awawawaw"
  [59]=>
  string(0) ""
  [63]=>
  string(0) ""
  [70]=>
  string(0) ""
  [146]=>
  string(0) ""
  [155]=>
  string(0) ""
  [66]=>
  string(0) ""
```

I want to get a hold of all indexes if it contains anything. How do you do this? I tried

```
foreach($code_ids as $code_id) {
  if(!empty($code_id)) {
     $index[] = $code_id;
  }
}
```

The problem in this is that it gets its value. I just want the index.

Answer (score 5):

Try it

```
array_keys(         // 2. returns keys as new array
    array_filter(   // 1. removes all empty items
        $code_ids));
```

[array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter), [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)

Comment: +1, but be aware that `array_filter()` will remove items with the value of 0 or false as well, even `'0'` as a string.